# Django-admin, generic foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

У модели есть generic foreign key, сделал limit чтобы можно было добавлять только несколько моделей

Теперь искал и не смог найти ответа, как сделать чтобы `object_id` был не просто `PositiveIntegerField`, а можно выбирать из существующих моделей

То есть не вводить число, а был выбор из текущих

`models.py`

```
class MainPage(models.Model):
    limit = models.Q( models.Q( model = 'post') | models.Q( model = 'category'))
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=limit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

`admin.py`

```
class MainPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = { 'generic': [['content_type', 'object_id']]}
```

Но это не то

Наше старую статью, которая идеально подходит -  http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/admin-site-widget-generic-relations-django/

Но на django 2.x выдает ошибку в шаблоне

`django 'tuple' object has no attribute 'render'`

C `AutocompleteGeneric` пробовал работать, но постоянно выдает ошибки, находил методы установки до 3 версии, получается устанавливал 2.6, после чего появлялись другие ошибке при импорте

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ

вот на github https://github.com/mqsoh/django-gfklookupwidget 
Правда с import проблемы, но я в дальнейшем просто склонировал и чу-чуть исправил как мне надо, а так можно использовать напрямую